# Where to get realistic data for ABC-Costing in textile industry

Tags: data-request

first, let me explain what I am trying to do. For my graduation work with focus on automation i would like to show the impact of "Sewbots" (SoftWear Automation) on garment manufacturing.

My teacher suggested doing so by applying activity-based costing for a production line and then, by hypothesy,  on a partly automated one. (I know one system of SewBots costs approx. 50.000 - 100.000, it can replace up to 17 workersand needs 1 supervisor for up to 5 production lines.

I found some data on abc in garment production but none of it seems complete.  (Ex. https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://journal-archieves30.webs.com/602-625.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjzgveL6JvbAhWKvBQKHXdgCTMQFjAAegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3rvr7q_1CVtTEZT2uU0mVH)

Can someone suggest some sources where to get complete realistic data ofactivities, cost drivers, rates etc.. in textile industry?

Every advice is appreciated.
Thank you very much
Martin

Comment: You can try asking here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/